# get integer from a string in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that represents a temperature. This string is dynamically parsed from a website and it can contain also negative values. For example, it can be -1 C, or 2 C and so on.

I want to get only the integer value. Here is my code:

```
$temp_number = preg_replace("/-?[0-9]+/", '', $value); 
echo "Temperature : ". $value . "Number : ".$temp_number."<br/>";
```

I thought that the temp_number should be the extracted number BUT it is the C for example. Here is my output.

```
Temperature : 0℃   Number : ℃
```

What should I use? I do not want to replace the string, I want to extract it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intval` seems like an obvious solution here, much simpler than a regex. (Your example makes it appear as if the string is always just a number followed by C, and temperatures aren't usually recorded in decimals, so: `intval`.)

Proof: http://ideone.com/DjI3jG

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
$temp_number = preg_replace("/[^-0-9]+/", '', $value); 
echo "Temperature : ". $value . "Number : ".$temp_number."<br/>";
```

The regex of `[^-0-9]+` basically states that it should strip away anything that is not a `-` or a number.

Answer (score 2):

1.Like Jessica said above `intval` is much simpler

```
$value = '0℃';
$number = intval($value);
echo $number; // which is 0 integer
```

2.Also, you can use `filter_var`

```
$value = '0℃';
$number = filter_var($value,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, Use `/[^0-9]/` in your regex

```
$number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $value);

echo "Temperature : ". $value . "Number : ".$number ."<br/>";
```

Comment: `/\D+/` is a simpler equivalent pattern.

Answer (score 0):

try this use `"/[^0-9]/"` as regex

```
$value="100";
$temp_number = (int)preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $value); 
echo "Temperature : ". $value . "Number : ".$temp_number."<br/>";
```

output:

```
Temperature : 100Number : 100
```

Comment: `/\D+/` is a simpler equivalent pattern.